# Excel Generating a formula based sequence based on levels

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What I am trying to achieve is the following

```
 ID            Name       Level 
 1             ABC           1
 11            ABC           2
 11001         ABC           3
 1100101       ABC           4
 110010101     ABC           5
 11001010101   ABC           6
 11002         ABC           3
 1100201       ABC           4
 110020101     ABC           5
 11002010101   ABC           6
 11002010102   ABC           6
 110020102     ABC           5
 11002010201   ABC           6
 11002010202   ABC           6
 11002010203   ABC           6
 2             ABC           1
 21            ABC           2
 21001         ABC           3
 2100101       ABC           4
 210010101     ABC           5
 210010102     ABC           6
 21002         ABC           3
```

I have the following code in excel to generate this code but I m not able to achieve the above, can anyone help me with this, please find below the formula I am using:

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF($D$9:D18,1),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=1,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,2),COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=1,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,2),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=2,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,3),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=2,ROW(D9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,3),"000"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=3,ROW(D9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,4),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=3,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,4),"00"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=4,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,5),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=4,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,5),"00"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=5,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,6),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=5,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,6),"00"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=6,ROW(D9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,7),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=6,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,7),"00"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=7,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,8),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=7,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,8),"00"),""),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=8,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,9),TEXT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))=8,ROW($D$9:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))),0))):D18,9),"000"),""))
```

Basically I am trying to generate the code in the ID field automatically, let me explain how it works: ID are set using the Levels field for Level 1 its the first digit in the ID field it represents, for Level 2 its the 2nd digit for level 3 its the 3 digits after 2 digits , and afterwards 2 digits for each levels. Furthermore once a level 1 has been assigned it cannot to assigned to another level 1 therefore the second level 1 will be give the next number, its first level 2 will have 1 as number and 2nd level 2 within will give it 2 and the same goes for the following code.

The problem with my code is that it calculates the value fine till the first level 1 and its below code but however its start behaving incorrectly as I go down the codes, it should not print the level code for 4,5,6 and more if I am generating a level 3. these are some of the problems I am facing

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to explain precisely how the required output is generated. Since you say your formula doesn't work, that not helping anyone understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: what columns do you have? what column values are you going to generate?

Comment: Levels is basically the Column "D" which I m using in my formula

Comment: Wow - that's some function.

Comment: Shouldn't the second last line be `21001010101`? Also, why is level 1 only one digit, level 2 four and level 3 two, etc.?

Comment: @pnuts: Either it's level 5 - or if it's level 6 then it should be `21001010101`! At least to my understanding! :-)

Comment: @pnuts: true - but all but this row at least have an odd but deterministic pattern...

Comment: @PeterAlbert thats just the coding convention I m following Level 1 and 2 are 1 digts , Level 3 is 3 digits and then following 2 digits for each level

Comment: @PeterAlbert last line is Level 3 so for the coding convention it should pick the last level 1 and 2 codes which makes it 21 and as there is no other Level 3 under the last Level 2 so the code becomes 21003 as there is no level 4 and above, this should the final code

Comment: See my updated answer - still had a small bug that I fixed. Apart from the second last row, it produces exactly the result you showed in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it although I use a helper column.  It could all go in one cell but it gets way longer then a formula I would like to see

If you have levels in column A you will calculate a decimal ID in column B and an actual ID in column C

cell B2=1 (since the formula doesn't work on the first of the series)

other cells in column B use the formula

`=INDIRECT("B"&MAX(ROW($A$2:A2)*($A$2:A2<=A3)))+INDEX({1,0.1,0.0001,0.000001,0.00000001,0.0000000001},MATCH(A3,{1,2,3,4,5,6},0))`

Entered with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

This formula finds the value of the decimal ID from the last row that has a level less then or equal to itself (indirect part)

the index looks up the Level and adds the right amount to the value found in the first part of the formula.

Column C uses the formula

`=B2*10^IF(B2=INT(B2),0,LEN(B2)-FIND(".",B2))`

which just rounds the number up to a integer by finding the number of decimal points (if statement) and then raising 10 to that power and multiplying by the decimal ID.

If you really need to do it in one column you could paste the whole first column everywhere you see `B2` in the second formula but that would make the formula totally illegible.

[image]

Gordon

**PART 2**

As per the request for more levels I've had to use a different technique which deals mainly with text.

Instead of using the arrays built right into the formulas I created a seperate table which makes it a little easier to handle, you could reference this with named ranges, a seperate chart or just put the numbers right in the formula if you want.

[image]

For the cells you enter the Level and sigfigs.

Digits kept is sigfigs from the level above minus 1 (`M3=L2-1`)

Digit Add start is the sigfigs from level above (`N3=L2`)

Digits add length = sigfigs from level - sigfigs from level above +1 (`O3=L3-L2+1)

For the actual index formula the first row has the value 1 again and then in cell B3 use

`=LEFT(B2,INDEX($M$2:$M$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0))) & MID(B2&"00000",INDEX($N$2:$N$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0)),INDEX($O$2:$O$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0)))+1`

To break this down

`=LEFT(B2,INDEX($M$2:$M$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0)))`

means keep the left part of the index above.  Find the length to keep from the digits keep column

`MID(B2&"00000",INDEX($N$2:$N$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0)),INDEX($O$2:$O$12,MATCH(A3,$K$2:$K$12,0)))+1`

means add a bunch of zeros to the end so you can use a level higher then the current one.  Find the digit you need to start with, and the number of digits you want to use.  Add 1 to this value.

The & sign between them will concatenate them together.

Comment: I am not able to replicate your example .. How can I do it.. column B just returns 0

Comment: are you putting the formula in with Ctrl+Shift+Enter? are the levels in column A? are the levels between 1 and 6?

Comment: Yes, and only 0 is returned, if possible can you upload the file so I can test if its work

Comment: Not sure whats going on then, I recreated the spreadsheet and copied the formula in and it works fine, maybe the formatting isn't showing decimals, does column C work? Is the formula being wrapped in {} after you press ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: I was able to replicate this and it works fine, can you please help me extend this to 9 Levels till level 8 it should 2 digits, however for level 9 i m not able to recreate 3 digit value .. the final level 9 should be like 110010101010101001  without the dashes

Comment: @gtwebb it seems that excel does not support decimal value more than 14 points and the code is 17 decimal points is there an alternative to add the 9th Level in the code?

Comment: I would suggest going with Peter Albert's solution and doing as you said and breaking it down into two parts you may need some error checking in the formulas to make it work

Comment: I was not able to make it work and I think Peter Albert solution does not work with 20,000 fields as perfectly as yours !!

Comment: I've added a different solution that should work, as stated you can put it all in the formula the same way I did in part 1 it just gets very long.

Answer (score 2):

Place `1`in `A2`.

In cell `A3` and below, place this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(C3,
LEFT(A2,1)+1,
IF(C2=1,A2*10+1,LEFT(A2,2)+1),
IF(C2=2,A2*1000+1,LEFT(A2,5)+1),
IF(C2=3,A2*100+1,LEFT(A2,7)+1),
IF(C2=4,A2*100+1,LEFT(A2,9)+1),
IF(C2=5,A2*100+1,LEFT(A1,11)+1))
```

Comment: can you extend this formula to 9 Levels ? with the level 9 with 3 digits

Comment: why don't you do it? you just have to copy the last row and adjust the numbers accordingly! :-)

Comment: It does not work .. as with 9 Levels the total digit count is 18.. and excel does not process after 16 significant values so I am not able to do it.. I think I can accomplish this using Concatenate and breaking the levels in 2 formula to achieve this but not sure

Comment: Can you use multiple columns? Btw: better edit/clarify your question - then it gets reopened and other people might contribute a better solution. Best mention the requirement of going up to level 9!